# How to recover a replaced file via FTP?

Tags: ftp, file-recovery

I’m developing a website, and I replaced a file (`.css`). I did it wrong. How can I recover this old file?

I only have FTP access.

Comment: Where is the old file.  Was it replaced on your computer or the remote computer?  If it's on the remote computer, it might be possible with low-level file recovery on that machine before it gets overwritten, but that couldn't be done via FTP.

Comment: I did it in a remote computer (server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file you overwrote has been around long enough, the system administrator of the server may have a backup. You might inquire.

Answer (score 1):

> I’m developing a website, and I replaced a file (`.css`). I did it
>   wrong. How can I recover this old file?

If you overwrote a file via FTP on a remote server, the file is simply overwritten and gone with no way to recover it.